# How to do Row-wise calculations in a dataframe Without using for loop - R

Tags: r, dt

This is the output I am aiming to calculate:

[image: Am trying to do the following ROICDelta Calculations]

This is the code I have iterating through each row of the dataframe and doing the calculation, which I am aware is not the best way to do it

```
STOCKsbyQuarter_LOCF_Ticker <- subset(STOCKsbyQuarter_LOCF, STOCKsbyQuarter_LOCF$Ticker == input$STOCKTickers)

for( i in 1:length(STOCKsbyQuarter_LOCF_Ticker$ROIC)){       
     STOCKsbyQuarter_LOCF_Ticker$ROICDelta <- (STOCKsbyQuarter_LOCF_Ticker$ROIC[i+1] - STOCKsbyQuarter_LOCF_Ticker$ROIC[1]) / 
                                              (STOCKsbyQuarter_LOCF_Ticker$date[i+1] - STOCKsbyQuarter_LOCF_Ticker$date[1])     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- STOCKsbyQuarter_LOCF_Ticker
df$ROIC_Delta <- (df$ROIC - df$ROIC[1])/(df$Date - df$Date[1])
```

`ROIC_Delta` for the first row will be `NaN`. You can replace it by an appropriate value.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
dt = setDT(STOCKsbyQuarter_LOCF_Ticker)

dt[ , "ROIC Delta" := (ROIC - shift(ROIC))/as.numeric(difftime(Date, shift(Date),units = c("days")))]
```

Comment: @ForeverLearner Is ROIC Delta supposed to be calculated off of the first ROIC and date value? or the preivous row? code above does previous row. If you want first change shift(x) to x[1].

Comment: It is to be calculated off the first value and yes thank you!